# Привязка определённых переменных к кнопке в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

У меня при запуске программы генерируется рандомное кол-во кнопок, их я помещаю в Content объекта Scroll View и при наведении на кнопку, должно появляться справа окно с определёнными параметрами, которые индивидуальны для каждой кнопки, всего их 3. 
Но я не могу понять, каким образом привязать 3 переменные к каждой кнопке?

Comment: панель которая появляется служит просто для вывода информации? Чисто отображение параметров кнопок ?

Comment: @Andrey Да, просто при наведении на кнопку - отображается индивидуальная информация для той кнопки, на которую наведён курсор, это весь функционал.

Comment: А вот эти "переменные" где хранятся? Что мешаете привязать колбек к каждой кнопке с определенным индексом, насколько я помню, юнити позволяет передавать как минимум 1 параметр в колбек.

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял то вам нужен интерфейс с методом Display. Повешайте на кнопки скрипты  унаследованы от этого интерфейса. И когда вызываете панель то просто обращайтесь к методу Display который по разному реализован у каждой кнопки с их параметрами и просто выводите информацию в панели

Comment: Это я примерно понимаю как сделать. Мой вопрос относится больше к тому, как правильно реализовать метод DIsplay?

Comment: Добавьте в скрипт кнопки нужные вам параметры и выводите их в дисплее